# how to pass an array of multiple values from route to view in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-8

I am trying to pass an array of (id, name) from countries table to a view
to show to the user to select options of country

in **web.php**

```
Route::get('/register/one', function () {
  $countries = DB::table('countries')->pluck('id', 'name');
  return view('Register.createyourprofile')->with('countries', $countries);
});
```

I don't know how to pass it correctly and get in view
I am trying to get like this but it's not working

```
<optgroup label="All" id="getDynamicCountryName">
  @foreach ($countries as $country)
  <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</optgroup>
</select>
```

please help me to pass correctly and get it correctly in the blade

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure but wouldn't it be `<?php foreach ( ... ) { ... } ?>`?

Answer (score 1):

pluck return associative array format.Also make note `pluck('columnName1','columnName2');` here `columnName1` is `value` and `columnName2` is `key` in array

Result will be

```
[
   'columnName2Value'=> 'columnName1Value',
   'columnName2Value'=> 'columnName1Value',
]
```

In route

```
Route::get('/register/one', function () {
  $countries = DB::table('countries')->pluck('name', 'id');
  return view('Register.createyourprofile', compact('countries'));
});
```

It should be

```
<optgroup label="All" id="getDynamicCountryName">
  @foreach ($countries as $key=>$country)
  <option value="{{$key}}">{{$country}}</option>
  @endforeach
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The pluck helper method is used to retrieve a list of specific values from a given $array.**

But you are trying to access `$country->id` as an object but it actually a collection (kind of array but not array). You can loop through collections

You have to use `foreach` loop with `key => value`

In your blade file change the `foreach` loop like this:

```
 @foreach ($countries as $countryName => $countryId)
      <option value="{{ $countryId }}">{{ $countryName }}</option>
  @endforeach
```